# To get results in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to know is there any chance to get our result in an edittext not in textview without using any button. That is when we place cursor on the edittext field, the result we want to print should be in the field. Is there anyone who could help vth this.?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you reformulate your question? Do you mean that you want some text to auto-paste into an EditText when you click in it?

Comment: Yes.. I want to display my text or number in edittext when I click on it..yes like auto-paste bro.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but it should work I think

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.setText("whatever")
        } 
    }
});
```